# Grails spring security facebook plugin redirecting to wrong page

Tags: facebook, spring, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

I'm using the Grails Spring Security Core plugin and now adding in Facebook authentication via the Facebook Authentication for Spring Security Core plugin.  I'm able to authenticate with Facebook, however it's always redirecting back to an incorrect URL.  I want to redirect to `localhost:8080/rar/user/home`, however after login I'm redirected to `localhost:8080/rar/#_=_`.  When logging in through a standard login form I am redirected properly to `localhost:8080/rar/user/home`.

My FB app settings has `http://localhost:8080/rar/` for the Site URL.  I'm using these plugins:

```
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
compile ":spring-security-ui:1.0-RC1"
compile ":spring-security-facebook:0.15.2-CORE2"
```

And have these config settings:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/user/home'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.filter.type='redirect'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.domain.classname='mvp.FacebookUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.domain.appUserConnectionPropertyName='user'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.appId='<APPID>'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.secret='<SECRET>'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.filter.redirect.failureHandler='redirectFailureHandlerExample'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.autoCreate.roles=['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_FACEBOOK']
```

I don't think it matters for this problem, but I have a FacebookAuthService that implements create() to search for existing users with the same email address as the Facebook user, and merges the accounts if it finds one.  Currently my redirectFailureHandlerExample does nothing but log a message, which is never hit.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the following setting too at config.groovy

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.facebook.filter.redirect.successHandler='redirectSuccessHandlerExample'
```

And at the resources.groovy:

```
beans = {  
   redirectSuccessHandlerExample(org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler) {
       defaultTargetUrl = '/rar/user/home'
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a way to know from which page the login was clicked. For example if login to facebook was clicked from <url>/list. And id there is a possiblity that login can be done from multiple urls, Is it possible to know from which url the login was clicked so that the redirect can be done to that url.